# Continuous map and irrational numbers

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

My question is the following :

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous map such as each irrational number is mapped to a rational number (i.e. $f(\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q})\subset\mathbb{Q}$). Show that $f$ is a constant map.

**What I have done :**

Let's suppose that $f$ is not a constant map, i.e. it exists $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y).$ As $f$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem gives us that $[f(x),f(y)]\subset f([x,y]).$ But, as $$f([x,y])\subset f(\mathbb{R})=f(\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}\,\cup\,\mathbb{Q})=f(\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q})\,\cup\,\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{f(p_n)\}\subset\mathbb{Q}\,\cup\,\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{f(p_n)\},$$ where $p_n$ is a sequence which describes $\mathbb{Q},$ we would get that $[f(x),f(y)]$ is a subset of a countable set and so is countable, which is a contradiction and so $f$ is constant.

**My questions :**
Is my proof correct, and if yes, does someone see an other way to answer it ?

Thank you for your comments, and happy new year !

Comment: Your proof is absolutely correct. But for simplicity sake I'd have simply said: Suppose there exist x,y s.t f(x) != f(y).  The irrationals are dense in R so there exists an irrational d between f(x) and f(y).  By IVT there exist a c where f(c) = d.  Which is a contradiction.  It's the exact same idea as yours but a bit simply.

Comment: @fleablood : But how can I get the nature of $c$ by this way ? Perhaps it would be a rationnal number, I just know it is between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks good! As a side note, as you asked for alternative methods, you do not have to formulate the proof by contradiction. Note that the image of $f$ is 
$$
f(\mathbb{R})=f(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{Q})=f(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\cup f(\mathbb{Q})=A\cup \{f(q_n):n\geq1\}
$$
Where $A\subset \mathbb{Q}$ and $q_n$ is an enumeration of the rationals. Thus $f(\mathbb{R})$ is countable, and a continuous map with a countable image is constant.

Comment: Indeed, no need to use contradiction here ! Just a precision, when you say "a continuous map" to conclude your proof, is it "a continuous real map for the usual topology" or are you thinking about something more general ?

Comment: @Baloown with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Right, thank you very much for your answer and precisions !

Comment: or you could just say $f(\mathbb R)$ is connected and countable, so it must be trivial (every nontrivial connected metric space is uncountable).

Comment: Pedantic note: I would not use a notation such as $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} f(q_n)$ since $f(q_n)$ is not a set. I'd use $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ f(q_n) \}$ or more simply $\{f(q_n) \ |\ n\geq 1 \}$.

Comment: @chi fixed it, thank you for the catch

Comment: @ForeverMozart : nice argument that I did not know, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Very good proof! It is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !